New Firebase v1 FCM not sending alerting sounds
We have been using Firebase for sending messages to apps for a while now but had to upgrade to v1 platform as the legacy was decommissioned. We were able to get messages to go through but now when we send, the alerting sounds (notifications) are not being sounded. I think it has to do with how were sending the payload.
here is what we used to send (with the values in pound signs):
<cfset bodyData = {  "to": "#get_messages.UDID#",
 "priority": "high",
 "notification" : {
   "title": "test Crisis",
   "body" : "#body#",
   "EMB_id": "#get_messages.EMB_id#",
   "message_log_id": "#get_messages.message_log_id#",
   "reference_alertID": "#get_messages.reference_alertID#",
   "recipient": "#recipient#",
   "recipient_firstname": "#get_recipient.sub_firstname#",
   "recipient_lastname": "#get_recipient.sub_lastname#",
   "recipient_profile_image": "http://crisis.wensnetwork.com/wens_crisis/app_profiles/#get_recipient.app_profile_image#",
   "reply_resolve": "#get_messages.reply_resolve#",
   "reply_public": "#get_messages.reply_public#",
   "msg_type": "1",
   "tracker": "#get_messages.tracker#",
   "app_message_id": "#get_messages.app_message_id#",
   "content_available": "true", 
   "sound": "#sounds#",
   "content_available": "1",
   "apns-priority": "5",
   "image": ""
    },
 "data" : {
   "title": "test Crisis",
   "body" : "#body#",
   "EMB_id": "#get_messages.EMB_id#",
   "message_log_id": "#get_messages.message_log_id#",
   "reference_alertID": "#get_messages.reference_alertID#",
   "recipient": "#recipient#",
   "recipient_firstname": "#get_recipient.sub_firstname#",
   "recipient_lastname": "#get_recipient.sub_lastname#",
   "recipient_profile_image": "http://test.com/test_crisis/app_profiles/#get_recipient.app_profile_image#",
   "reply_resolve": "#get_messages.reply_resolve#", 
   "reply_public": "#get_messages.reply_public#",
   "msg_type": "1",
   "tracker": "#get_messages.tracker#",
   "app_message_id": "#get_messages.app_message_id#",
   "content_available": "true", 
   "sound": "#sounds#",
   "content_available": "1",
   "apns-priority": "5",
   "image": ""
   }

} >
That worked perfectly in the old platform.
But now we had to change to the new JSON posting structure:
<cfset bodyData = '{ "message": {
    "token": "#get_messages.UDID#",
    "notification": {
    "title": "test Crisis",
    "body": "#body#",
    "image": ""
    },
    "data": {
    "title": "test Crisis",
    "body": "#body#",
    "EMB_id": "#get_messages.EMB_id#",
    "sound": "#sounds#",
    "message_log_id": "#get_messages.message_log_id#",
    "reference_alertID": "#get_messages.reference_alertID#",
    "recipient": "#recipient#",
    "recipient_firstname": "#get_recipient.sub_firstname#",
    "recipient_lastname": "#get_recipient.sub_lastname#",
    "recipient_profile_image": "http://test.com/test_crisis/app_profiles/#get_recipient.app_profile_image#",
    "reply_resolve": "#get_messages.reply_resolve#",
    "reply_public": "#get_messages.reply_public#",
    "msg_type": "1",
    "tracker": "#get_messages.tracker#",
    "app_message_id": "#get_messages.app_message_id#",
    "content_available": "1",
    "apns-priority": "5",
    "image": ""
    }
    }
    }' >

Big difference is I see that there is nothing assigned to "notification" tag and suspect that is will the tones are not coming through. The "sound" tag is where we add what tone to play. But nothing is happening.

Of course it took more research and reading but I found it. Here is the answer for anyone else that encounters.
I was not using the following tag in addition to notification & data:
"apns": {
                        "payload": {
                            "aps": {
                                "sound": "#sounds#"
                            }
                        }
                    }

So here is the full code with the addition:
<cfset bodyData = '{ "message": {
                    "token": "#get_messages.UDID#",
                    "notification": {
                    "title": "test Crisis",
                    "body": "#body#",
                    "image": ""
                    },
                    "apns": {
                        "payload": {
                            "aps": {
                                "sound": "#sounds#"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "data": {
                    "title": "test Crisis",
                    "body": "#body#",
                    "EMB_id": "#get_messages.EMB_id#",
                    "sound": "#sounds#",
                    "message_log_id": "#get_messages.message_log_id#",
                    "reference_alertID": "#get_messages.reference_alertID#",
                    "recipient": "#recipient#",
                    "recipient_firstname": "#get_recipient.sub_firstname#",
                    "recipient_lastname": "#get_recipient.sub_lastname#",
                    "recipient_profile_image": "http://test.com/wens_crisis/app_profiles/#get_recipient.app_profile_image#",
                    "reply_resolve": "#get_messages.reply_resolve#",
                    "reply_public": "#get_messages.reply_public#",
                    "msg_type": "1",
                    "tracker": "#get_messages.tracker#",
                    "app_message_id": "#get_messages.app_message_id#",
                    "content_available": "1",
                    "apns-priority": "5",
                    "image": ""
                    }
                    }
                    }' >

